# Client to Server Communication for rsyslog

Tags: vmware, rsyslog

I have two Ubuntu OS in VMware Virtual Machine: one of them is the client ( Ubuntu 14 ) and the other one is the server ( Ubuntu 15 Mate). I want to forward apache logs (access and error logs) from the client OS, to the rsyslog on the server OS remotely, how can I do this?

Comment: You've mentioned you tried some configs. You might want to include which ones you already tried into your question